# how to locate element with selenium webdriver for below html

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have an issue clicking on the below HTML:

```
<div id="P7d2205a39cb24114b60b80b3c14cc45b_1_26iT0C0x0" style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;font-weight:500;" class="Ab73b430b430a49ebb0a0e8a49c8d71af3"><a tabindex="1" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="var rp=$get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl10_ReportControl');if(rp&amp;&amp;rp.control)rp.control.InvokeReportAction('Toggle','26iT0C0x0');return false;" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){var rp=$get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl10_ReportControl');if(rp&amp;&amp;rp.control)rp.control.InvokeReportAction('Toggle','26iT0C0x0');}return false;"><img border="0" src="/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=10.0.30319.1&amp;Name=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RendererResources.TogglePlus.gif" alt="+"></a>&nbsp;2013</div>
```

I have used the below script to click anchor inside a div tag. For the above html code it is not fixed only end part of id example "26iT0C0x0" is fixed. The script that I have used is:

```
WebElement e1=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[ends-with(@id,'26iT0C0x0')]/a")));
e1.click();
```

Comment: Post the HTML content.

Comment: It is div inside this div there is anchor tag, I want to click on that anchor tag and anchor tag has no such thing to identify it. html is posted above.

Comment: There isn't any html above...

Comment: sorry due to some error html was not showing up in the question.Please review now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'contains' method within an xpath lookup:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'26iT0C0x0')]")
```

Comment: Selenium is giving me following error along with Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //div[ends-with(@id,'26iT0C0x0')]/a                                             The xpath expression '//div[ends-with(@id,'iT0C0x0')]/a' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 53 milliseconds                         although i have increase the time out for wait also used the contains method but still not working.

Comment: If you're using 'ends-with' you need to be using xpath2.0 which isn't supported in all browsers, hence I suggested using 'contains' which is available in xpath1.0 which is supported in more browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to consider CSS selector alternative as CSS working faster, than xpath.
So 'contains' in attribute in CSS stands for '*=', for example 
if we want to find attribute by 'CSS' ending in this: `<htmlTag A="blablaCSS" >` we need do the following:

```
String CSSselector="htmlTag[A*=CSS]";
```

and you get this element searched.

So considering your example CSS selector be like:

`String cssSearched="div[id*=26iT0C0x0] a"`;

also try to click not on link - `a`
but on parent div as well:

`String cssSearched="div[id*=26iT0C0x0]"`;

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSearched));
```

hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Rwolands already mentioned: the xpath-Function 'ends-with()' isn't supported in Selenium 2.
Also, if you maybe consider to use chromeDriver in the future, I would recommend clicking the image, not the anchor, see:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/clicking-issues

edit:
Also your IDs are looking generated. I wouldn't count on them for a stable test-environment.